# Slick pick game - boolean functions and return statements

Tags: java, function, boolean

I am working on a project, and I have written the code that I know how to do. I am having multiple problems, and I don't know whether I should post the entire project code at once or just focus on one problem at a time.

The directions for the games are: "At the start of the game, both the player's and Slick's scores are set to zero. For each turn, the player picks one number from the pool. That value is added to the player's score. Slick gets the sum of all the remaining numbers in the pool that divide evenly into the player's pick. The player's pick and it's divisors are then removed from the pool. For each turn, Slick must be able to get at least one number. If the player does not have any picks left, the game is over and Slick gets the sum of all remaining numbers in the pool. The highest score wins."

If the player's pick is valid, the list of divisors is printed; if the player's pick is not valid, an error message should be printed and the prompt should appear again. For a pick to be legal, it must be in the pool, and it must have at least one divisor in the pool. My code is below:

```
//Name          : pickValidity
//Description   : This funtion determines if the player's pick is valid.
//Parameters    : The pool array and the user's pick, in that order.
//Return        : True/false indicator.  
public static boolean pickValidity(int[] pool, int size, int pick){
    int low=0;
    int high=size-1;
    int mid;
    int poolIndex=0;
    boolean found=false;
    boolean isValid=false;

    while(low<=high && !found){
        mid=(low + high) / 2;
        if(pick == pool[mid]){
            found = true;
        }else if(pick < pool[mid]){
            high = mid-1;
        }else{
            low = mid+1;
        }
    }
    if(found){
        while(pool[poolIndex] < pick && !isValid){
        if(pick % pool[poolIndex] == 0){
            isValid = true; 
        }else{
            isValid = false;
        } 
        poolIndex++;
        }
    }
    return(isValid);
}
```

Below, I've added my call statements. When I run the program and deliberately enter non-valid picks, the prompt comes up again, but after I enter another number, the program stops. How do I make it keep going?

```
        // User Input
    printPool(pool, size);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter a non-prime value listed in the pool above: ");
    pick=read.nextInt();

        // Pick Validity
    while(!(pickValidity(pool, size, pick) && poolValidity(pool, pick))){
        System.out.println("Pick is invalid.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter a non-prime value listed in the pool above: ");
        pick=read.nextInt();
    }

        // Data Processing
    numDivisors = getDivisors(pool, divisors, pick);

        // Output Section
    printDivisors(divisors, numDivisors, pick);
    System.out.println();
    printScores(divisors, size, pick);
    System.out.println();


    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Program Ended");  
   }
```

Please & thank you!

Comment: First off, **focus on one problem at a time**. Secondly, I'm not sure exactly what your question is.

Comment: So, for the entire project, I have created a pool of random numbers from 1-100 and assigned them to an array & then printed the pool of numbers. A player is then prompted to pick a non-prime number from the pool, and if both the pool and the number that is picked is valid, then the divisors of that number are printed. My problem is with testing whether the pool of numbers and the player's pick are valid. I don't know if I'm on the right track with my code, and I also keep getting an error message saying that a return statement is missing.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you want to return "isValid" from PoolValidity?

Another guess is that you want to return at once when you determine that the pool is valid, ie "isValid=true"

I would also have a closer look at your if-test. I'm not convinced that it is correct.

Comment: I've updated my code, but I have a new question regarding when an invalid number is entered. I put the new question in my updated code, so I wouldn't run out of room in this comment.

Comment: Not entirely sure if i understand your new question, but i think you now are missing the "for each turn" part of your directions. The answer to that question would be to have a loop that repeats the entire process until a given criteria is met. So, perhaps, after you have picked a number and done whatever you need to do with it, you could start over with printPool()?